# Add Months to Timespan for Job Experience

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, jobs

#### Background

In the `Experience` section of my Stack Overflow CV, there's no place for me to put in jobs that have lasted less than a year (such as short term contracts).

Right now if I put a three month contract in, it makes it seem like I was employed there for an entire year, instead of 3 months.

It's pretty standard to have something like one of the three following headers for a job on your CV:

```
June 2008 - September 2008 (3-month Contract)
June 2008 - September 2008 (Contract)
June 2008 - September 2008
```

#### Feature Request

Add the ability to narrow down employment to Month/Year, and not just Year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already do this -- it's a free-form field with no validation.

I'll add this as example text so it is clearer that this is OK.

Comment: The reason i thought you couldn't was that the box didn't seem to allow Month to be inserted; just year.